# Extending expiry date of facebook access token in graph api beyond 2 months

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am working on facebook page wallpost automation using python

I have automated posting on a fb page that i own by using ***facebook graph api post***
So i do this by sending a HTTP POST request to https://graph.facebook.com/mypagename/feed

with access_token and message as POST paramaters

I generate the access token by using ***graph api explorer*** by selecting my app that i am using and giving it permission to **manage my pages**

Intitially the access_token use to expire in 2 hours

To extend the expiry date to 2 months i send HTTP GET request to this url

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=my_app_id&client_secret=my_app_secret&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=old_access_token

the response is a json string with **new access_token** and **expiry** time in seconds

the expiry time of new access token is now 60 days.

Now is it possible to extend expiry time beyond 60 days??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short-Term and Long-Term Tokens**

User access tokens come in two forms: short-lived tokens and long-lived tokens. Short-lived tokens usually have a lifetime of about an **hour or two**, while long-lived tokens usually have a lifetime of about **60 days**. You should not depend on these lifetimes remaining the same - the lifetime may change without warning or expire early. See more under handling errors.

So the only way left is to regenerate using code **just before 60 days.**

Make a GET request to graph api and filter out the access token from the JSON response

Get your user id here http://findmyfacebookid.com/

Now

Request

```
GET /{user-id}/accounts
```

Response

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "category": "Product/service",
      "name": "Sample Page",
      "access_token": "{access-token}",
      "id": "1234567890",
      "perms": [
        "ADMINISTER",
        "EDIT_PROFILE",
        "CREATE_CONTENT",
        "MODERATE_CONTENT",
        "CREATE_ADS",
        "BASIC_ADMIN"
      ]
    }, 
}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

Answer (score 4):

You can use following api from facebook to refresh token life to 60 days and just when the token is about to expire, call the same api again with-in 60 days to refresh its life back to 60 days from that point of time Token expire is present in expires parameter and its value is in seconds

Replace CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET with their actual value

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=&client_secret=&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=

in ACCESS_TOKEN, put the actual token value without appending "access_token="

Comment: In this one I am getting `Missing redirect_uri parameter.`

Answer (score 0):

Your *Page Access Token* will not actually expire. Please read the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension):

> **Extending Page Access Tokens**
>
> Apps can retrieve a page access token from Page admin users when they
> authenticate with the manage_pages permission. If the user access
> token used to retrieve this page access token is short-lived, the page
> access token will also be short-lived.
>
> To get a longer-lived page access token, exchange the User access
> token for a long-lived one, as above, and then request the Page access
> token. The resulting page access token will not have any expiry time.

So if you use a long-lived **user** access token, you will get an infinite **page** access token.

Comment: It would be great if you can explain again with screenshots. I use Graph API explorer to get access token. What Next ?

Comment: I have checked https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension and they said longer-lived page access token expires after 60 days. Did you check this?

Comment: It does not work like this anymore. Data access lasts for 3 months in long-lived tokens.