# Facebook feed pages where I am admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I know this question has been frequently asked but I trying to do a post on a Facebook page since 2days without any results.

Here is what I have :

- An application, with an APP_ID and an APP_SECRET
- A facebook page with an ID
- My personal ID

I want to programatically post a feed on the page, and don't know how all of this works..

I tried to request via

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET

which gives me a access token, but when I try to

https://graph.facebook.com//feed?access_token=TOKEN

and that doesn't work.

I also tried to do that with requesting my access_token, but it needs a redirect_uri, and the token is given is the new URL and required an action (accept) permissions. That's not what I want.

I just want to publish on a page where I am the admin..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 types of access token:

1. User Access Token (Include page actions.)
2. App Access Token (Modify and read the app settings. It can also be used to publish Open Graph actions.)
3. Page Access Token (Specific to page actions.)
4. Client Token (rarely used)

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET

What you've done is retrieve the App Access Token, which was nothing to do with page.

So, in order to post Facebook feed pages as admin, you should use User Access Token OR Page Access Token instead.

**User Access Token**:

You will have to go through authorization dialog to retrieve your User Access Token:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=145634995501895&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html%3Fdisplay%3Dpage&response_type=token&fbconnect=1&perms=manage_pages%2Cstatus_update

Make sure you granted both **manage_pages** and **status_update** permission, as shown in the **perms=** parameter above. The reason can be found here: [why does posting to facebook page yield "user hasn't authorized the application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796138/why-does-posting-to-facebook-page-yield-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application/15943045#15943045)

Then you do HTTP POST request (e.g. message=hello) to your page on https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_ID/feed?access_token=YOUR_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

**Page Access Token**:

You have to use User Access Token to retrieve Page Access Token via API calls:

1. https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=YOUR_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN (Get all pages token)
2. https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_ID?fields=access_token&access_token=YOUR_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN (Get specific page token by page ID)

Then you do HTTP POST request (e.g. message=hello) to your page on 3 ways:

1. https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_ID/feed?access_token=YOUR_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
2. https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=YOUR_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
3. https://graph.facebook.com/feed?access_token=YOUR_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN

**Update:**

I suggest you to manually granted a User Access Token(e.g. Login/authorization dialog would appear, and user need to manually click to accept APP permission request, you can't programatically web scraping to do this first step, as it's violate TOS of the Facebook platform), 
then extend it to long-live(Expired 2 months) via https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=my_app_id&client_secret=my_app_secret&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=User_Access_Token

And now you have long-live User Access Token, and then call https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=LONG_LIVE_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN to get NEVER expired Page Access Token. You can debug the Page Access Token at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken?q=YOUR_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN

As you can see, the **Expires** date is **Never**:

[image]

**Documentation**:

1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
2. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app (No such thing post to page as admin)

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I had understood a lot of this, but I don't understand how to get my user access token permanently. In your solutions, I have to manually call my token, and then I can do the other calls programatically. What I'm searching for is to do all the stuff programatically. If I misunderstood something, please explain me, cause I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to call token programatically(i.e. user must interact to granted APP permissionｓ), as it's violate TOS of the platform. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381454/extending-expiry-date-of-facebook-access-token-in-graph-api-beyond-2-months answered that "long-lived user access token, you will get an infinite page access token", so i suggest you to use Page Access Token for your task.

Comment: Calling call graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=LONG_LIVE_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN   produced some errors, but I finally got my long live page access token by requesting graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token&access_token=LONG_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN. Many thanks for ur help, I really needed that :).