# Facebook Graph API - What is the correct Access Token for my purpose?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm creating a webpage for a business, I want to pull specific information via facebook (business hours, etc). I'm successfully doing that through Graph, however I have to regenerate a new token because they expire.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Is there anyway for me to have a token that doesn't expire like an API integrator key would work with other integrations? I don't have an app and I don't want a user to log in, I can use my login creds to authenticate the webpage to access the access code if needed.

All of the information I read is that you have an app that has the user log in and generate an access token on their behalf.

(this is for 100% GET requests, no POST requests)

Comment: Or is there another API I should be utilizing to grab this information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381454/extending-expiry-date-of-facebook-access-token-in-graph-api-beyond-2-months ?

Comment: That appears that I would need to have an app gain manage_pages permissions, is that the correct answer?